# Stack Menu – Access Stack Overflow from the Menu Bar

Tags: app, mac-os-x

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image: Desktop Screenshot]

### About

[Stack Menu](https://basilsalad.com/os-x/stack-menu/?utm_campaign=StackMenu&utm_source=StackApps&utm_medium=catalog&utm_content=StackMenu) stays in the macOS menu bar to provide quick access to Stack Overflow. Search for programming problems and share answers without moving out from your development environment.

#### License

Freeware

#### Download

- [Product Info](https://basilsalad.com/os-x/stack-menu/?utm_campaign=StackMenu&utm_source=StackApps&utm_medium=catalog&utm_content=StackMenu)
- [Direct Download](https://shine.basilsalad.com/download.php?id=1)

#### Platform

- macOS, 10.13

### Contact

- [Basil Salad Software](https://basilsalad.com)

### Code

- Swift

Answer (score 6):

My immediate feedback:

- I’m not normally a fan of applications in place of browser interfaces (Slack is still in a tab for me), but this seems potentially quite useful. (With the usual caveat that my job is basically tied to activity on the sites.)
- Switching to a new site required me to click the Google button again, but I didn’t need to use my password or 2FA, which is nice.
- The hamburger menu can get lost in the top bar:

  [image: Before clicking]

  That can make it impossible to get the sidebar menu:

  [image: After clicking]
- It’s awkward to type Markdown without preview. (If only we had [CommonMark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238957/1438) for this!)
- The logo is too similar to the SO logo. Ideally, you’d be able to use our logo, but I don’t think that’s authorized. (See [our trademark guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance).) My best suggestion is to use something like a question mark that indicates what you’re getting if you click on it, but doesn’t create the impression that it’s coming from Stack Exchange Inc. (I’m not a lawyer nor have I consulted one. This is just an immediate reaction.)
- I love the way you’ve rearranged the layout, but I wish I could change the screen size and location.

At any rate, great job! I’ll be trying it out for a while and see if it sticks!

Comment: It occurs to me the problem with the hamburger might be that I have a diamond on the top bar that most users won't have. If needed, I can log out and test with a sock puppet that doesn't have a diamond.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the logo to be less similar to SO.